# How to connect to an EKS service from outside the cluster using a LoadBalancer in a private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

I am trying to expose An EKS deployment of Kafka outside the cluster, within the same VPC.

In terraform I added an ingress rule for the Kafka security group:

```
  ingress {
    from_port = 9092

    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 9092

    cidr_blocks = [
      "10.0.0.0/16",
    ]
  }
```

This is the service yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bootstrap-external
  namespace: kafka
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "10.0.0.0/16"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: "sg-0....d,sg-0db....ae"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
      targetPort: 9092
  selector:
    app: kafka
```

When trying to connect from another instance, belonging to one of the security groups in the yaml,
I seem to be able to establish a connection through the load balancer but not get referred to Kafka:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-47 kafkacat]$ nc -zvw10 internal-a08....628f-1654182718.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com 9092
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.0.3.151:9092.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.05 seconds.
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-47 kafkacat]$ nmap -Pn internal-a0837....a0e628f-1654182718.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com -p 9092

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-02-28 07:19 UTC
Nmap scan report for internal-a083747ab.....8f-1654182718.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com (10.0.2.41)
Host is up (0.00088s latency).
Other addresses for internal-a083747ab....36f0a0e628f-1654182718.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com (not scanned): 10.0.3.151 10.0.1.85
rDNS record for 10.0.2.41: ip-10-0-2-41.us-east-2.compute.internal
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9092/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-47 kafkacat]$ kafkacat -b internal-a083747abf4....-1654182718.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:9092 -t models
% Auto-selecting Consumer mode (use -P or -C to override)
% ERROR: Local: Host resolution failure: kafka-2.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/2: Failed to resolve 'kafka-2.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092': Name or service not known
% ERROR: Local: Host resolution failure: kafka-1.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/1: Failed to resolve 'kafka-1.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092': Name or service not known
% ERROR: Local: Host resolution failure: kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092/0: Failed to resolve 'kafka-0.broker.kafka.svc.cluster.local:9092': Name or service not known
^C[ec2-user@ip-10-0-4-47 kafkacat]$

``
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved the Kafka connection by:

1. Adding ingress rule to the Kafka worker security group (We use Terraform)

```
  ingress {
    from_port = 9094

    protocol = "tcp"
    to_port = 9094

    cidr_blocks = [
      "10.0.0.0/16",
    ]
  }
```

1. Provisioning each broker a load balancer service in Kubernetes YAML (note that the last digit in the nodePort corresponds to the broker stateful set ID).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata: 
  name: bootstrap-external-0
  namespace: kafka
  annotations: 
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "10.0.0.0/16"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: sg-....d,sg-0db14....e,sg-001ce.....e,sg-0fe....15d13c
spec: 
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - 
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9094
      port: 32400
      nodePort: 32400
  selector: 
    app: kafka
    kafka-broker-id: "0"
```

1. Retrieving load balancer name by parsing `kubctl -n kafka get svc bootstrap-external-0`.
2. Adding DNS name by convention using Route 53.
3. We plan to automate by terraforming the Route53 after load balancer is created.